# Show Tipsy tooltip without hover?

Tags: javascript, hover

all. I made one form for registration, but I want to show the messages for errors in my tooltip Tipsy. For this I must made some function to show the tooltip without hover on the ID object. I try to add new parameter in the default options like this:

```
$.fn.tipsy.defaults = {
        delayIn: 0,
        without_hover: true... }
```

And second in this function $.fn.tipsy = function(options)....
I add one check if the without_hover is true to show the tipsy like this:

```
if(options.without_hover == true) tipsy.show();
```

but it doesn't work. I will be happy on any solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [tipsy plugin](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/), the syntax for manually showing a tooltip is:

$(selector).tipsy("show");